# Color change of nitroglycerin. Potential hazard?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, nitro-compounds

I recently nitrated around (~7mL) of glycerol through a process I have performed many times before. The nitroglycerin has been stored for ~3 weeks, and I noticed a drastic change in color from clear to an opaque dark green/blue.

I'm not sure exactly what occurred, but I am assuming some impurity in the final product was oxidized over the course of its storage. Most likely due to the fact that the container storing the fuming nitric acid I used for the nitration broke and the remaining acid was salvaged for this reaction.

Is there any chance the nitroglycerin could be unstable in its current state? I have not disturbed it and would like to dispose of it safely.

Comment: Well, nitro is a  hazard itself, and if something strange is happening with it then it's even less reliable. Hard to tell if it's, say, more prone to explosion, but lack of explosion when it's needed is also a problem.

Comment: You can easily absorb nitroglycerin in solid absorbent such as _diatomite_ (like in dinamite) for safety.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the situation correctly Mathew Mahindaratne.